# How to check programatically if i will be able to install an apk

Tags: android, performance, apk, package-managers, android-install-apk

my app downloads an `apk` file and i want to check if i can open that archive and install it before installing it.

I know that i can read the archive with the package manager and that it will be null if it is not a valid `apk`, but right now, the package manager is not null, but i am still not able to install that `apk` file (through an intent).

It gives me an error from the os saying "There was an error while analysing the package"

So basically i just want to check if that `apk` is valid in a different way, rather than checking if the package manager is null.

Is there a way to check for this ?

EDIT:

Here is a bit of code.

The file destination is a copy of a file that i get as an argument of the method where all of this code is included.

```
  String updatePackageName =getPackageManager()
            .getPackageArchiveInfo(fileDestination.getAbsolutePath(), 0)
            .packageName;
    int updateVersionCode = getPackageManager()
            .getPackageArchiveInfo(fileDestination.getAbsolutePath(), 0)
            .versionCode;
    String updateVersionName = getPackageManager()
            .getPackageArchiveInfo(fileDestination.getAbsolutePath(), 0)
            .versionName;

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(fileDestination), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: How would we know how you try to install?

Comment: I don't know if that is what you are asking, but the instalation is through an intent on Android. The thing is that when i get the apk file i can check if the packageInfo or the packageManager from the archive are null, but is there any other way?
Basically i just want to know if the apk is a valid apk.

Comment: `the instalation is through an intent`. I gladly believe that. But what does it help only telling? What can we comment on it without code?

Comment: Added the code, thanks for your help

Comment: `startActivity(intent);`. And you should tell us what happens then instead of only telling that you cant install it. How would we know what happens?

Comment: I get an alert dialog saying that there was an error while analysing the package.